# I need to configure ssl nginx with chef. What is best way to roll out ssl certificate?

Tags: chef-infra

Where should be stored SSL certificate (i don't think it is nice idea to store it in a cookbook) - and how it should be rolled it with chef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using any third-party tools, Chef provides [data bags](https://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html), particularly encrypted data bags, that are made for this.

The main downside of using encrypted data bags is you need a mechanism to deliver to each node the secret that can decrypt the data bag. The system works fine, though, and gets the job done.

[Chef-Vault](https://github.com/Nordstrom/chef-vault) is a third-party tool that builds extra features and security on top of data bags, you could check it out.

And in case you're using AWS, you could consider [Citadel](https://github.com/poise/citadel), or even an [AWS KMS](http://aws.amazon.com/kms/) implementation (where you could encrypt your SSL cert, store it with the cookbook, and use AWS KMS to decrypt the file containing the cert during the Chef run.